# How to aggregate data in Hadoop stack?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I'd like to aggregate data into "buckets" by some arbitrary criteria (like in ElasticSearch, not Hive bucketing).

I think, it would be best way to explain what I want to accomplish, is to present it on data, so:

The basic problem:

**Step 1**

I've got data in such structure (currently imported to HIVE ORC table):

```
id | category | subcategory | value
1    foo        bar           3
3    foo        bar           5
5    foo2       bar1          7
6    foo        bar2          1
9    foo2       bar           5
11   foo        bar           10
```

Now I'd like to group the data by id, by the bucket size of 5, so I achieve:

**Step 2**

```
bucket_no | id | category | subcategory | value
1           1    foo        bar           3
            3    foo        bar           5
            5    foo2       bar1          7
2           6    foo        bar2          1
            9    foo2       bar           5
3           11   foo        bar           10
```

So I get 3 buckets to work on. That leads me to to

Advanced problem:

On (or probably after) step #2 I'd like to perform some operations on buckets, for example find an average value for each category:

**Step 3**

```
bucket_no | category  | AVG(value)
1           foo         4
            foo2        7
2           foo         1
            foo2        5
3           foo
```

OK, back to #2, I'm aware I could just group the data by FLOOR(id%5), then by category, and get AVG of value (I'm sticking to SQL way of thinking, because it's technology I'm familiar with), ending with this data would make me partially satisfied, but I'd like to know how to create bucketed aggregations and which tool (HIVE, Spark or maybe other should be used), so I can solve Real World Problem:

**Step 4**

I've got data from step #1, sorted by id. Now I change my bucket size to 11. I'd like to:

1. find a category, let's call it X
2. create bucket from data having (X.id-5) >= id <= (X.id +5)
3. find average values for each subcategory in bucket
4. create list of pairs subcategory: AVG(value) and join them with category (sub-bucket)
5. remove all data found in step 2, to make sure they won't be duplicated in another bucket
6. repeat until all data are processed and cleared

My final result, I'd like to achieve should look like this:

**Step 5**

```
bucket_no | category | subcategory | AVG(value)
1           foo        bar           4
2           foo2       bar1          7
                       bar           5
3           foo        bar2          1
4           foo        bar           10
```

Comment: SQL-ish approach (define a function which maps records to categories) is a good approach and trivial to express with SQL (Hive, Spark SQL) or DataFrame API. Iterative procedure you've described in step #4 is not. It is hard to scale and depending on the data with result with poor resource utilization.